# Interval Partitioning with additional limitation(locks&size)

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to figure out the most optimal way to solve this variation of the interval partitioning problem(given a set of lectures with start and finish times s and f, find the least number of classrooms needed to schedule them so that no two overlapping lectures coincide in the same classroom). Here is it in more details: http://algorithmsandme.in/2016/05/interval-partitioning-problem-greedy-algorithm/

The first limitation would be that certain lectures could be locked in to certain classrooms. For example, a certain lecture requires certain equipment, and therefore can only use classroom A because classroom A is the only one that has that equipment. This would mean certain lectures would be locked to certain classrooms.

The second limitation would be the size of each classrooms. Some lectures might have more students than others, and some classrooms might be able to accommodate more students than others. This would mean that certain lectures would have to be restricted to certain classrooms, and possibly also that bigger groups would also have to be prioritized to bigger classrooms to minimize the number of used classrooms.

The typical approach would be to use a greedy algorithm but this approach seems somewhat inadequate given these two limitations. Locked lectures would also have to be resolved first, with flexible lectures then solved taking into consideration starting time, finishing time and lecture/classroom size into consideration.